# Make context menu events specific to the section the menu was pulled up

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, jquery-events

**Issue:** The context menu is functioning, but it remembers the click events if you pull up the context menu on multiple divs.

**To recreate:** Right click one section. Click outside of the menu to close it (don't choose an option). Click on another section and choose an option. If you delete, it will delete both sections to which the menu was pulled up. If you choose to move the section up down, it will move the first section to which the menu was pulled up.

**Question:** How can optimize the following JS/Jquery to make keep the events of the menu specific to the section in which the menu was pulled up?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2jrj0j9/4/)

```
$(".templateSection").contextmenu(function (event) {
    var thisTemplate = this;
    // Avoid the real one
    event.preventDefault();

    // Show contextmenu
    $(".custom-menu").toggle(100).    
    // In the right position (the mouse)
    css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
    $(".editArea").css('outline', 'none')
    //Delete section menu button
    $("#menuDelete").click(function () {
        $(thisTemplate).remove();
        $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
    });    
    //Move sections up and down
    function firstAndLast(container) {
        firstAndLast($('#container'));
    }    
    $('.menuUp, .menuDown').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var parent = $(thisTemplate).closest('.templateSection'),
            grandparent = $(thisTemplate).closest('#container');

        if ($(this).hasClass('menuUp')) {
            parent.insertBefore(parent.prev('.templateSection'));
            firstAndLast(grandparent);

        } else if ($(this).hasClass('menuDown')) {
            parent.insertAfter(parent.next('.templateSection'));
            thisTemplate.clearQueue();
        }
    });

    // Hide menu if the document is clicked somewhere
    $(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {
        //left mouse down
        switch (e.which) {
            case 1:
                // If the clicked element is not the menu
                if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {
                    // Hide it
                    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
                }
        }    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed JS to the following code. I will change the accepted answer if a more optimized solution is given.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2jrj0j9/12/)

```
//Replace default context menu on right click
$(function () {
    $('.custom-menu').hide();
    $(".templateSection").contextmenu(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        thisTemplate = this;
        $(".custom-menu").css({
            top: event.pageY + "px",
            left: event.pageX + "px"
        }).fadeIn(200);
    });
});

//Delete Section
$("#menuDelete").click(function () {
    $(thisTemplate).remove();
    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});

//Move sections up and down
$('.menuUp, .menuDown').click(function () {
    var parent = $(thisTemplate).closest('.templateSection');
    if ($(this).hasClass('menuUp')) {
        parent.insertBefore(parent.prev('.templateSection'));
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('menuDown')) {
        parent.insertAfter(parent.next('.templateSection'));
    }
});

$(document).mousedown(function (e) {
    //left mouse down
    switch (e.which) {
        case 1:
            // If the clicked element is not the menu
            if (!$(e.target).parents('.custom-menu').length > 0) {
                $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
            }
    }
});
```